# Modules and prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, binomial-theorem

Let's say that $p$ is prime number, $z$ is natural number and our form $\frac{p-1}{2^z}=n$ and is even. $p>n$. From binomial theroem $n^x$ ($x$ is natural number) = form in photo. So is $$n^x \equiv \bigg(\frac{1}{2^z}\bigg)^x \pmod{p}$$ the truth ? Better to look at photo so you can properly see what I want to show you.

I don't know why, beacuse it makes kinda sense to me, it is not true. For example $p=13$ and $z=1$ and $x=p-2$ or any other I think. Also I don't know if mod can be written as fraction and if it is written like that what I need to do to make it  natural number?

..

[image]

Comment: BTW, we can (sometimes) give a sensible definition to fractions in modular arithmetic. Eg, $\frac14\equiv 10\pmod{13}$ because $4×10\equiv 1\pmod{13}$. This always works for a prime modulus. But for composites, divisors of the modulus have no inverse. Eg, in mod 15, there's no solution for $3x=1\pmod{15}$.

Comment: It is fine @PM2Ring now i know what to do and I am satisfied with answer i was given :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not necessarily true. $$\bigg(\frac{p-1}{2^z}\bigg)^x\equiv\bigg(\frac{-1}{2^z}\bigg)^x\pmod{p}$$

So only if $x$ is even you have $$\bigg(\frac{p-1}{2^z}\bigg)^x\equiv\bigg(\frac{1}{2^z}\bigg)^x\pmod{p}$$

---

EDIT: you cannot always find the residue. $\frac{1}{2^z}$ is the modular inverse of $2^z$, ususally denoted with $2^{-z}$ Those do not have a formula. Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse).

Comment: Thanks :)) Now I got what i wanted.

Comment: For an odd prime $p, 2^{-1}\equiv(p+1)/2\pmod p$. And using Fermat's little theorem (or Euler's theorem) $$a^x\equiv a^{x\mod(p-1)}\pmod p$$ for $a$ coprime to $p$.